# Is memcached a kind of webservice running on some webserver?

Tags: memcached

I have reado couple of tutorial about memcached.  Basically its a key value data store. I am not clear is it like web service running on some webserver like tomcat or node.js?

Comment: You're talking about [this memchached](http://www.memcached.org/), right? From the documentation as well as the sources it seems it is _not a Java-based software_ at all.

Comment: @thomas i have removed java tag. But question is still same

Comment: I wasn't refering to the tag but to your actual question: "... is it simple _java _process ...or using _tomcat_(a Java-based server)" - answer: it seems not to be Java-based at all so neither of the two.

Comment: @Thomas your are right. Actually i should have written a thread running for infinite time . Will correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @thomas said, it's not java so no, it's not running tomcat.

Also, it is a key/value data store, and it is not running a webserver at all, nor using it internally. It's probably save to say that a"webserver" is out of the question. It might be using some sort of framework internally, that I don't know personally, but that's the point where I kinda have lost the goal of your question :)

Comment: i have updated my question to make it clear. Actually i am trying to understand how it works internally